# What is the most efficient way to conditionally log information?

Tags: java, performance, coding-efficiency

I don't really know what is the best way to log information from an application. Most of what I've seen is programmed like this:

```
while(true) {
   //code
   if(debug == true) {
      log(info);
   }
end
```

And I've thought of using two separate loops like this:

```
if(debug == true) {
   while(true) {
      //code
      log(info);
   }
else {
   while(true) {
      //code
   }
}
```

But that has the problem of being twice the work to change later on. The last solution, which I think is probably the best, is to use something like a lambda expression and pass an empty implementation to use without debug:

```
public void loop(Debug debug) {
   while(true) {
      //code
      debug.log(info)
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   loop(d -> {
      //print to file, command line, etc. OR do nothing
   });
}
```

Any clarity on issues or unintended consequences would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance You don't need any conditional statements

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to invent a bicycle. Use existing logging frameworks and follow their guidelines.

Whatever you will think of - you will need to get over same problems that are already solved there.

For example https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x
Or http://www.slf4j.org/